# UITableView reloadData does not make UITableView reload its data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have methods implemented for datasources like `heightForHeaderInSection` or `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I have a `MasterView` - `DetailView` class implementation which implemented on different class. When I open the `MasterView` which will then open a `DetailView` for an item I select on `MasterView`, the `DetailView` will call all the datasources (touch the breakpoints). But after I return to `MasterView` and select another item, it will open `DetailView` again but show the old data, and all the datasources breakpoints are not touched at all. I have called the `[detailTableView reloadData]` manually from `MasterView` after populating `DetailView`'s properties with new data and before bring the `DetailView` to screen, but the table won't refresh. What went wrong?

Comment: Make sure `detailTableView` is not `nil`.

Comment: @NicolasMiari you're right. I was updating the wrong tableView. That took me hours! Thanks!